# Shuffle Array So No Two Keys Are in the Same Location

Tags: javascript, arrays, shuffle

I'm working on a Secret Santa app, and I'm matching up people by shuffling up an array of users, and then iterating through it using a `for` loop, then invoking the function if a key in the first array is identical to a key in the second array. However, this is causing some problems when being executed within the application, and results in it hanging at times. In addition, the theoretical maximum execution time for this function is infinite, and something I want to avoid.

Is there a way to shuffle an array so that no two keys are in the same location without reiterating the function if it fails?

The code I'm using (not implemented into the application itself) is as follows:

```
//underscore utility library
var _ = require('underscore');
//pretty console colors
var colors = require('colors');
//fs module to write to file
var fs = require('fs');
//path utilities
var path = require('path');
//arr will contain the UIDs of the participants.
var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41, 42, 43, 44, 45, 46, 47, 48, 49, 50];
//sArr will be the pairings.
var sArr = [];
//plain-text data
var writeMe = '';
//i for an i
var i = 0;
//var declaration to shut up the linter
var justDoIt;
var writeIt;
var shuffleIt;
var checkIt;

var shuffleIt = function () {
  //use Underscore.js' shuffle function on the array.
  sArr = _.shuffle(arr);
};

var checkIt = function () {
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    //check to make sure that there are no duplicates. 
    //otherwise, politely complain
    if (arr[i] === sArr[i]) {
      //well fuck. both are the same. Let's do it again
      console.log(arr[i] + "=>" + sArr[i]);
      console.log("ERROR".red + "\n==================\n");
      justDoIt();
      return;
    }
    //otherwise, print current pairing to console
    writeMe += arr[i] + '=>' + sArr[i] + "\n";
    console.log(arr[i] + '=>' + sArr[i]);
  }
  //we're done!
  console.log("All good!".green);
  //let's write it out
  writeIt();
  return;
};

var justDoIt = function () {
  //roll it
  shuffleIt();
  //check it
  checkIt();
};

var writeIt = function () {
  //write it to a file
  fs.writeFileSync(path.join(__dirname, 'pairings.txt'), writeMe);
};
//init
justDoIt();
```

Comment: Way too complicated. Shuffle the array once, make a copy of it, transpose the elements in that copy by one. Voila, guaranteed unique match-ups.

Comment: @deceze What if the shuffled array was one away from having an exact match?

Comment: What does that mean?

Comment: @Saposhiente After the copy, all of them will be exact matches, but in a random order. Shifting them by one will make a set of random matches that are guaranteed to have no collisions.

Comment: @deceze Original {1, 2, 3, 4} Shuffled {4, 3, 2, 1} Shifted once {1, 4, 3, 2}

Comment: Is an exact match "non-random"?

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi You have to compare matches with the original array, not the shuffled version. One algorithm is to just shift the array by one, guaranteed to not match to self, but that's not random.

Comment: @Dinesh Not at all, in fact, it's fairly common in randomization. However, in my particular use case, it would foul up everything, since it's for a secret santa, and it'd suck to have to get a gift for yourself.

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi, I must admit you got a point :-)

Comment: @Saposhiente Actually, that would create the same problem, since a shuffled array compared against the original array could still contain collisions. By shuffling it once, then shifting a copy of the array by one, I'm guaranteed uniform distribution, as well as a collision free match up.

Comment: @Saposhiente I'm not sure who is replying to whom anymore. But `[4,3,2,1]` matched with `[1,4,3,2]` seems like a great result, no?

Comment: Anyone else notice this is for a secret Santa app... with only 1 day left before Christmas? that's a seriously tight deadline! ;-)

Comment: @scunliffe It's for an online community, for which I've been collecting signups for a week. I was hoping to have it finished earlier, but bugs threw in delays, so the Secret Santa is kind of going to run through the new year. Not ideal, but it could be worse :)

Comment: @deceze I see more clearly what exactly you meant by this algorithm. It's simple because it is not truly random: It is guaranteed to produce a gifting assignment such that if you follow a chain of one gift to the next, you always go through every person in the group before returning to your start; in a truly random shuffle, there will be many separate loops of gifts.

Comment: @Saposhiente I see what you mean. I'd think for the purpose of a Secret Santa, my algorithm should probably do just fine in practice. But for scientific completeness, I can see how that falls short.

Comment: @deceze I misread your solution, it works., comment deleted.

Comment: @deceze It does work fine for the secret santa. In fact, it might even be better in some aspects, in the sense that two people won't get each other.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The general term for a rearrangement where no element is in its original position is a *derangement*, and it's a fascinating problem.

You are looking for an *unbiased* (uniformly random), *non-rejection* (not "repeat until it works") algorithm for a random derangement.

It's not trivial.

This is one such algorithm (EDIT: it does not appear to be unbiased):

```
function derangementNumber(n) {
    if(n == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    var factorial = 1;
    while(n) {
        factorial *= n--;
    }
    return Math.floor(factorial / Math.E);
}

function derange(array) {
    array = array.slice();
    var mark = array.map(function() { return false; });
    for(var i = array.length - 1, u = array.length - 1; u > 0; i--) {
        if(!mark[i]) {
            var unmarked = mark.map(function(_, i) { return i; })
                .filter(function(j) { return !mark[j] && j < i; });
            var j = unmarked[Math.floor(Math.random() * unmarked.length)];

            var tmp = array[j];
            array[j] = array[i];
            array[i] = tmp;

            // this introduces the unbiased random characteristic
            if(Math.random() < u * derangementNumber(u - 1) /  derangementNumber(u + 1)) {
                mark[j] = true;
                u--;
            }
            u--;
        }
    }
    return array;
}

var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7];
derange(a);
```

You can look at [this paper](http://epubs.siam.org/doi/pdf/10.1137/1.9781611972986.7), [this slide deck](http://www.cs.upc.edu/~conrado/research/talks/analco08.pdf), or [this Mathematics question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/302057/generating-a-random-derangement) too.

Comment: This is fascinating! Thank you for the reply, though the comments actually gave me an answer that will work, though this may actually be something to pursue in future projects where I'm not on quite as much of a time crunch.

Comment: @BrandonAnzaldi, okay, though I do not believe the answer in the comments will work, or it will be a rejection algorithm, meaning you will have to repeat it until it works.

Comment: Actually, if it's shuffled, then copied, then shifted, it's a single action function, since the list is in a random order, and the copy is initially an exact copy of it. By shifting it, all collisions are resolved, meaning it isn't a rejection algorithm.

Comment: This doesn't guarantee that a member isn't shuffled to its original position. I thought that was an important criterion of the OP?

Comment: @PaulDraper—copying and pasting your code shows that it doesn't about half the time. Can you show where at the link it says members are guaranteed not to be returned to their original position? It does say that all permutations are equally likely, so even an exact copy of the original is possible (though increasingly unlikely as length increases).

Comment: @RobG, you are correct. I misread something. The derangement algorithm is *similar* to Fisher-Yates, which is a general permutation algorithm. Updated answer.

Comment: @PaulDraper—cool, but it now has 50% more code that it needs and runs about [*10 times slower*](http://jsperf.com/derage-functions) than it could. I suspect the repeated use of *map* and *filter* don't help. ;-)

Comment: @RobG, I'm not sure about 50% more code. Is derangeRG unbiased? The complexity of this answer is due in part to that consideration. (If the OP doesn't want unbiased, then I suppose there a lots of much simpler algorithms, like Brandon's). I definitely agree with 10 times slower...it's got all sorts of places to optimize, both constant factor and big-O (e.g. `derrangementNumber`). But doing that would make it longer and IMO even less clear than it already is.

Comment: @PaulDraper—I guess I can test for "biased-ness" by running it say 10,000 times and analysing the results. I'm sure the alternative can be optimised too, but clarity may be a casualty…

Comment: @RobG...cool, but be careful. With a 11-element array, say the first element winds up in the second spot 1k of 10k times. Cool, but what that didn't tell you was that every time that happened, the second element was always in the third position. I'd try it with small arrays (say, 5) where there are only a couple hundred outcomes, and you could tabulate the probabilities of all of them.

Comment: @PaulDraper—I tried it with 6 and 7 member arrays. Your solution doesn't seem to find all possible solutions (190 vs 265 for a 6 member array, and 1332 vs 1854 for a 7 member array). It does seem less biased though with the difference between max/min occurring sequence 153/18 for me and 113/35 for you (running both 100,000 times). If you're good at stats, you can work out if that's significant or not. ;-)

Comment: @RobG, they both appear to be biased..http://jsfiddle.net/2u2anjvs/1/ Hm....I'll think more on it.

Answer (score 2):

As was pointed out in the comments, by shuffling the initial array, then shifting it by 1 (or any number less than the length of the array) will yield a random sort.

Sample code:

```
// Underscore Utility Library, since I was using this anyway.
var _ = require('underscore');
// Example shuffle: [4,2,1,9,5,8,3,7,6]
var arr = _.shuffle([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]);
var sArr = _.union(_.rest(arr), [_.first(arr)]);

// Log out pairs.
for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i] + ' --> ' + sArr[i]);
}
```

An example output for this is:

```
6 --> 3
3 --> 1
1 --> 2
2 --> 4
4 --> 7
7 --> 5
5 --> 8
8 --> 9
9 --> 6
```

The caveat of this solution is that it's not truly random. It will create certain impossible situations. For example, with this solution, it would be impossible for two users to get each other. 3 cannot have 6 if 6 already has 3. It creates a chain-effect that will ensure a random ordering, and that each recipient pairing will be unpredictable without knowledge of the previous pairings, but it will not be truly random.

Comment: Not a truly random sort: it is guaranteed to produce a gifting assignment such that if you follow a chain of one gift to the next, you always go through every person in the group before returning to your start; in a truly random shuffle, there will be many separate loops of gifts.

Comment: @PaulDraper That would be correct, if it were being compared against the unshuffled array. However, in this case, it's being compared against the already shuffled array. If this were a key value pair, take a look at the example output. It creates a sort of "chain". This utilizes the already randomized order of the array to create a companion to it that will have the same order, but shifted, creating a sort of "chain", thus ensuring a non-rejectionary solution. The downside to this is yes, it's not truly random, since it's impossible for two people to get each other, but it still works.

Comment: Ah I see. The "problem" is that it is not random. There are some mappings that can never happen. Topographically, there is only one possibility: a single large loop. But you might be okay with that.

Answer (score 2):

The following seems reasonably random and guarantees that a member will not be returned to its original position:

```
// Return a new array that is a deranged version of arr
// Guarantee that no member retains its original position
function derange(arr) {

  // Make a copy of arr
  var c = arr.slice();

  // If arr.length is < 2, return copy
  if (c.length < 2) {
    return c;
  }

  var result = [];
  var idx, i, iLen;

  // Keep track of whether last member has been moved
  var lastMoved = false;

  // Randomly remove a member of c, with conditions...
  for (i=0, iLen=c.length - 1; i<iLen; i++) {

    // If get down to final two and last hasn't been moved,
    // swap last two and append to result
    if (c.length == 2 && !lastMoved) {
      result = result.concat(c.reverse().splice(0,2))
      break;
    }

    // Otherwise, select a remaining member of c
    do {
      idx = Math.random() * c.length | 0;

    // But make sure it's not going back in the same place
    } while (arr.indexOf(c[idx]) == result.length)

    // Add member to result
    result.push(c.splice(idx, 1)[0]);

    // Remember if last was just moved
    lastMoved = lastMoved || idx == c.length;

  }

  // Add the last member, saves a do..while iteration about half the time
  if (c.length) result.push(c[0]);
  return result;
}
```

Some results:

```
console.log(derange([1,2,3,4,5,6]));

 [6, 4, 2, 5, 3, 1]
 [4, 1, 2, 5, 6, 3]
 [5, 4, 2, 6, 1, 3]
 [4, 5, 2, 3, 6, 1]
 [4, 6, 1, 5, 2, 3]
 [5, 6, 1, 3, 4, 2]
 [2, 4, 6, 1, 3, 5]
 [2, 1, 4, 5, 6, 3]
```

It's impossible to preclude certain values from Math.random, so if you get one you don't like, there's no choice but to get another. So a do..while loop is used to ensure that a member originally at index *i* isn't moved to new index *i*. However, such collisions should be minimal. It would also be good to optimise the lookup of the original value other than using *indexOf*. Perhaps that only matters for very large arrays.

If it gets to the last two members and the last member of the original array hasn't been moved, it will simply reverse then append the last two members, which is the only possible outcome at that point.